# Отступ между началом сайта и картинкой

Tags: html, css

поидеи, на сайте, должен быть задний фон, и хедер ввиде картинки, но с хедером возникла проблема, он с какими-то отступами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
надо сделать чтоб их небыло: ни сверху, ни слева, ни справа

вот код:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Atrax</title>
  <style>
    body {
      background: url(bg.png) no-repeat;
      -moz-background-size: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: 100%;
      -o-background-size: 100%;
      background-size: 100%;
    }
    
    header {
      display: block;
      height: 30px;
      background: url(header.jpg) no-repeat center bottom;
      -moz-background-size: 100%;
      -webkit-background-size: 100%;
      -o-background-size: 100%;
      background-size: 100%;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
</body>

</html>
```

P.S: Извиняюсь за возможно слишком простой вопрос

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте в стилях добавить для `body`:
`margin: 0;`